# express.js - server listening but localhost refused to connect

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, server

Trying to get started with setting up basic server. This is my code:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.send('this is fubar'); 
})

app.listen(3000, '0.0.0.0', () => console.log(`listening on port 3000`));
```

When I run `node server.js`, `listening on port 3000` is logged.

But when I visit `https://localhost/3000` I get the message "This site cannot be reached. Localhost refused to connect."

I ran `netstat -ab | findstr :3000`, but got no results. I've also tried ports 5000 and 80. What else can I do?

Using windows 10.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You mentioned `https://localhost/3000`. One problem is that it should be `https://localhost:3000` (`:` instead of `/`), and another one is that you probably mean to use `http` on localhost. Try: `http://localhost:3000`